# jQuery sorting not working entirely in Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, safari

I have a jQuery script that organises rendered tweets and news items into a news feed.

This works perfectly in Firefox but renders slightly strangely in Chrome and completely weird in Safari.

```
$(".news-item").sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date($(a).attr("data-date")) > new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));
 }).each(function(){
    $("#news").prepend(this);
});
```

Here's the HTML returned in Chrome:

[image]

That's the second most recent news story being returned at the end of data set.

Here's the HTML returned in Safari

[image]

P.S. Sorry for the images - there's a lot of inner HTML per news item.

Comment: try `+new Date($(a).attr("data-date")) - +new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));`. You should return `-1,0,1` in sort to depict less than, equal to and greater than. Also when comparing dates, ALWAYS use `date.getTime()`. `+date` is a shortcut for it

Comment: Mate you've solved it! Put as an answer and I can accept =]

Comment: Thats alright. Glad I was able to help you.